# group by time interval in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I need to show data between time 06:00 - 18:00 and 18:00 - 06:00 at same time

this is sample Query I M Using. I can not retrieve second group data. How to do?

like 
1,
2,
3
comes in 06:00 - 18:00 range

and 4,
5,
6
comes in 18:00 - 06:00 range

```
SELECT     COUNT(cp.comm_pend_id) AS comm_pend_id, cp.UserID, um.Username, CONVERT(varchar, cp.submitted_date, 101) AS Date, SUM(cp.Earning) 
                      AS Earning, SUM(cp.total_commission) AS total_commission
FROM         dbo.comm_pending AS cp INNER JOIN
                      dbo.user_master AS um ON cp.UserID = um.UserID
GROUP BY cp.UserID, CONVERT(varchar, cp.submitted_date, 101), um.Username, cp.PaidStatus, CONVERT(varchar(10), cp.submitted_date, 108)
HAVING      (cp.PaidStatus = 'unpaid') AND (CONVERT(varchar(10), cp.submitted_date, 108) BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '18:00:00')
ORDER BY cp.UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve the second group because 18:00 is greater than 06:00, so there's nothing between them in the same day. For the second group you should filter like this:

```
((CONVERT(varchar(10), cp.submitted_date, 108) < '06:00:00' 
 OR 
(CONVERT(varchar(10), cp.submitted_date, 108) > '18:00:00')
```

Comment: i want to show both group data between 06:00 - 18:00 and 18:00 - 06:00

Comment: It would help if you show visually what you expect as an output for the query.

Answer (score 0):

A CASE statement might be able to help.  For example:

```
create table #times (num int, dt datetime)

insert into #times values (1,'2011-4-6 0:00:00')
insert into #times values (2,'2011-4-6 4:00:00')
insert into #times values (3,'2011-4-6 8:00:00')
insert into #times values (4,'2011-4-6 12:00:00')
insert into #times values (5,'2011-4-6 16:00:00')
insert into #times values (6,'2011-4-6 20:00:00')

select 
    sum(case when (datepart(hh,dt) between 6 and 17) then num else 0 end) as daySum,
    sum(case when (datepart(hh,dt) not between 6 and 17) then num else 0 end) as nightSum
from #times
```